# ChangeListener not fired unless source of ObjectProperty changed

Tags: java, javafx, observable

Using JavaFX8, how is it possible to to be notified, if only one attribute of an `ObjectProperty` changes, but the reference stays the same?

Following a concrete example using `ObjectProperty<KeyStore>`. The `java.security.KeyStore` holds lists for keys and certificates. I want to be notified, if an entry gets added, changed or removed.

```
public abstract class EntityController {
    protected ObjectProperty<KeyStore> trustStore = new SimpleObjectProperty<KeyStore>();

    public EntityController() {

    }

    public KeyStore getTrustStore() {
        return this.trustStore.getValue();
    }

    public void setTrustStore(KeyStore trustStore) {
        this.trustStore.set(trustStore);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<KeyStore> trustStoreProperty() {
        return this.trustStore;
    }


}
```

```
public class CertificatesTabPresenter extends PKIPresenter implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            this.getEntityController().trustStoreProperty().addListener((observableVal, oldTrustStore, newTrustStore) -> {
            trustStoreChanged(oldTrustStore, newTrustStore);
        });
    }


    @FXML
    private void addTrustStore(MouseEvent e) {
        File keyStoreFile = selectKeyStoreFile();
        if (keyStoreFile != null) {
            Optional<String> keyStoreType = selectKeyStoreType();
            if(keyStoreType.isPresent()) {
                Optional<char[]> password = insertPassword();
                if(password.isPresent()) {
                    try {
                        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType.get());
                        trustStore.load(null, null);

                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
                        trustStore.load(fis, password.get());


                        //This causes the changeListener to be notified because the reference changed
                        this.getEntityController().setTrustStore(trustStore);


                        //The changeListener won't be notified, because only the KeyStore changes internally but the reference stays the same
                        trustStore.deleteEntry(trustStore.aliases().nextElement());
                        this.getEntityController().setTrustStore(trustStore);
                        //This also won't notify the changeListener
                        String a = this.getEntityController().getTrustStore().aliases().nextElement();
                        this.getEntityController().getTrustStore().deleteEntry(a);


                    } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (CertificateException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        //TODO: password was wrong -> show error message
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant code is where the `ObjectProperty`s value gets set for the first time and afterwards one element is removed. The changeListener gets only informed when the `ObjectProperty`s value is set, but not when the value is changed.

My Question is: How can I achieve to be notified if the `KeyStore` gets updated even if the referenced object does not change?
Is there a built in way in JavaFX?

My intention is to display all contained certificates and keys in a `ListView` and update the `ListView` everytime a certificate gets added or removed to the `KeyStore` from within the changeListener. Maybe I'm completely on the wrong way and I should do it completely different?

Additional information:

```
this.getEntityController()
```

returns an instance of an `EntityController` which itself is held in an `ObjectProperty<EntityController>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a better way of dealing with this limitation so what I do is just do a set() of the modified object so the reference keeps being the same but the change gets propagated.

Comment: What do you think of the idea to write a simple wrapper class, which forwards every method call to the wrapped object and fires a `PropertyChangeEvent`? Currently I also do a set() call.

Comment: I've thought on that solution several times but I always end up thinking it's not worth it. The problem of the wrapper is that you have to delegate every method, so maintenance becomes a problem. Via proxy could be possible but I think it's an overkill. 

Maybe the best approach is just to create an utility that exposes a method forceChange() that does the reasignation of the property.

Comment: This approach does not seem to work anymore. The bject is marked as invalid only if `value != newValue`